# How to show random colors as a button background of our choice

Tags: android

i am working on app for kids..
i need that a button background changes randomly...with specific colors given by me.
and when user click the button toast shows the color name at that moment.

example: you clicked on color: RED

i know the use of random function but how to make changes to this function that it shows colors of my choice.

```
Random rnd = new Random(); 
int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));   
view.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

color list:

```
<color name="bright_pink">#FF007F</color>
<color name="red">#FF0000</color>
<color name="orange">#FF7F00</color>
<color name="yellow">#FFFF00</color>
<color name="chartreuse">#7FFF00</color>
<color name="green">#00FF00</color>
<color name="spring_green">#00FF7F</color>
<color name="cyan">#00FFFF</color>
<color name="azure">#007FFF</color>
<color name="blue">#0000FF</color>
<color name="violet">#7F00FF</color>
<color name="magenta">#FF00FF</color>
```

how to force random function to use only above colors.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create an Array of color codes and use it to pick random color codes of your choice. Or if you want to create an array in your resource file then you can also go by that approach.

colors.xml

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="colors">        
        <item>#ff0000</item>
        <item>#00ff00</item>  
        <item>#0000ff</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Code in activity class.

```
String[] allColors = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.colors);

Color.parseColor(allColors[0]) // red
Color.parseColor(allColors[1]) // green
Color.parseColor(allColors[2]) // blue
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an array of the colors you want to randomize.

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="color_names">
        <item>red</item>
        <item>green</item>
        ...
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Get the random color

```
Random random = new Random();
String[] colorArray = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.color_names); 
String randomColorName = colorArray[random.nextint(colorArray.length())];
String randomColorResource = "R.color." + randomColorName;
```

Set your button color.

```
findViewById(R.id.myButton).setBackgroundColor(randomColorResource);
```

Create toast message with the name of the color.

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
               randomColorName, 
               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: what were the results?

Answer (score 0):

Do this way

```
Field[] fields = R.color.class.getDeclaredFields(); 

    int[] colors = new int[fields.length]; // Make this variable global

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            colors[i] = fields[i].getInt(null);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }


    int color = colors[new Random().nextInt(colors.length-1)];
    view.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

Comment: this will set the bkg color light pink only....i want to change randomly between above mentioned colors...ex: firstly pink then after few milliseconds red then green...yellow..etc...etc.

Answer (score 0):

This might helps you.

Create a list of colors.

```
List<String> colors = new ArrayList<>();

colors.add("#00ff00"); //eg.Blue
colors.add("#ff0000"); // ...
colors.add("#ff00ff");
...
```

Get `Random` object.

```
Random random = new Random(0);
```

Now get the random value generated within bound of your list size.

```
int generatedRandomNum = random.nextInt(colors.size());
```

Now get the random color and set it to the view.

```
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colors.get(generatedRandomNum)));
```

Based on the `generatedRandomNum` (i.e. position of array) Toast the color name that you already noted like Blue.

Note: `Random` might generate same number in a sequence. To know more about random check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html). If you don't want to repeat the same value, you should put some more logic behind it.

Comment: thanks ashwin...i think it will work. i m going to try it and then update to you